# fancontrol: return to original state, not full speed when exiting?

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I have followed the instructions on [this page](https://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/) to control graphics card fan speed using `fancontrol`.

It worked, but the problem is, when exiting the programme, it does not restore the original fan controlling (that is, the default setting that came with Ubuntu or before running `fancontrol`) but makes the fan run at full speed all the time, which is obviously unacceptable. Is there anyway to change this behaviour? I mean, I want the original to be restored, not the full speed.

Answer (score 1):

The short solution is in changing of `MAX` parameter in `/usr/sbin/fancontrol`. Line 44 for fancontrol 0.71.